# Python PIP broken trying to update

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I tried to update pip today to version 20.0.2 from 19.2.3, but the install gave a huge error:

```
C:\Users\fizzy\Downloads\trivia-master>python -m pip install --upgrade pip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.752.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.752.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.752.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages\pip\__main__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from pip._internal import main as _main  # isort:skip # noqa
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.752.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.752.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\autocompletion.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.752.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main_parser.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli import cmdoptions
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.752.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\cmdoptions.py", line 24, in <module>
    from pip._internal.models.search_scope import SearchScope
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.752.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\models\search_scope.py", line 11, in <module>
    from pip._internal.utils.misc import normalize_path, redact_password_from_url
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.752.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\misc.py", line 21, in <module>
    from pip._vendor import pkg_resources
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.752.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3242, in <module>
    def _initialize_master_working_set():
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.752.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3225, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.752.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3267, in _initialize_master_working_set
    tuple(
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.752.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3268, in <genexpr>
    dist.activate(replace=False)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.752.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2776, in activate
    declare_namespace(pkg)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.752.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2275, in declare_namespace
    _handle_ns(packageName, path_item)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.752.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2208, in _handle_ns
    loader.load_module(packageName)
  File "C:\Users\fizzy\Downloads\trivia-master\google.py", line 6, in <module>
    from config import API_KEY, CSE_ID
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'config'
```

I ignored this error, thinking the new version happened to just not install, and tried to install LXML but gave this similar error:

```
C:\Users\fizzy\Downloads\trivia-master>pip install lxml
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.752.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.752.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.752.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages\pip\__main__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from pip._internal import main as _main  # isort:skip # noqa
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.752.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.752.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\autocompletion.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.752.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main_parser.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli import cmdoptions
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.752.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\cmdoptions.py", line 24, in <module>
    from pip._internal.models.search_scope import SearchScope
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.752.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\models\search_scope.py", line 11, in <module>
    from pip._internal.utils.misc import normalize_path, redact_password_from_url
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.752.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\misc.py", line 21, in <module>
    from pip._vendor import pkg_resources
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.752.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3242, in <module>
    def _initialize_master_working_set():
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.752.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3225, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.752.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3267, in _initialize_master_working_set
    tuple(
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.752.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3268, in <genexpr>
    dist.activate(replace=False)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.752.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2776, in activate
    declare_namespace(pkg)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.752.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2275, in declare_namespace
    _handle_ns(packageName, path_item)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.752.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2208, in _handle_ns
    loader.load_module(packageName)
  File "C:\Users\fizzy\Downloads\trivia-master\google.py", line 6, in <module>
    from config import API_KEY, CSE_ID
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'config'
```

I can't reinstall pip either as it just gives me the same error when running pip uninstall pip. How do I fix this?

Comment: Run it from a different directory. It looks like you `google.py` in your current directory is masking a real module.

Comment: How did you install pip in the first place? Brew? Git Clone? Have you tried deleting the whole directory and reinstall that way?